# Heat an outdoor water tank to 10°C? (with an electric heater)

Tags: heating, water-heater, outdoor

**I have a stock tank full of water in a unheated greenhouse.**

The greenhouse is located east of Toronto, Ontario, Canada, where the temperatures occasionally go down to -25degC in winter.

[image]

**I would like to continuously heat the water in the tank to around 10°C.**

- It would be acceptable if the temperature of the water occasionally dipped to approx. 5°C.
- It would also be acceptable if the temperature of the water rose occasionally (or continually) up to approx. 30°C.

**I would prefer to use electricity to heat the water for these reasons:**

1. I assume maintaining a constant-ish temperature would be easiest with an electric heater.
2. Low risk of fire.
3. No risk of carbon monoxide or gas leak.
4. Generally easy. Plug it in, and go to the pub.

**How can I heat the stock tank of water electrically?**

Comment: Something like a **[stock tank de-icer](https://www.tscstores.com/1500W-SINKING-STOCK-TANK-DE-ICER-WITH-GUARD-P11099.aspx)** seems like it would be ***almost*** ideal.

The problem is that the units are designed to keep water from freezing; not for keeping the water at 10degC.

Comment: Make sure you use a 240V heater. You'll thank me later, to be more precise, when provisioning electrical service to the location.

Comment: @Harper What's the reason?

Comment: Presuming you have to carry electricity some distance to this location... You can get away with much thinner wire/cable, since the voltage drop losses will be only 1/4 as much.  Spec it both ways, it's a real eye opener.

Comment: adding insulation to the tank will go a long way to help prevent it from freezing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for a "tankside heater adjustable thermostat" like this one

https://www.miller-mfg.com/product/71502.html

may be suitable.

Comment: Good idea! I can't find them for sale in Canada, but I did come across [aquarium heaters](https://www.petsmart.ca/fish/heating-and-lighting/heaters/eheim-jager-trutemp-aquarium-heater-16566.html?cgid=300119). They might do the trick.

Comment: https://www.uline.ca/BL_8190/Drum-Heaters